# Display PostScript from within Java

Tags: java, postscript

Is there some sort of Display PostScript element that can be added to a GUI in Java?  I am much more fluent in PostScript than in Java, and I need to do some more complicated shapes and hit detection, which would be far easier using a Display PostScript system.

Is there such a library in existence?  If there is, what is it/where can I go to find it?

I have searched on google for it, but I can't find anything that really could do what I want, because of the large number of only partially-relevant results my searches have turned up.

Comment: There's Toastscript, but I don't think they added DPS.... There may be a way to interface with ghostscript as a library. It has the level-2 insidedness-testing operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can do it with Ghost4J :

```
// load PDF document
PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
document.load(new File("input.pdf"));

// create renderer
SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();

// set resolution (in DPI)
renderer.setResolution(300);

// render
List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);
```

If you want to render Postscript instead of PDF : used PSDocument class instead. The full example is available [here](https://github.com/zippy1978/ghost4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ghost4j/example/SimpleRendererExample.java).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ghost4J](http://ghost4j.sourceforge.net/). It provides features like converting .ps to .pdf and rendering .pdf-s using ImageIO, which can be applied as a solution to your problem.